# How to find close-vote questions for a particular tag?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, search

As of today, there are some 53.5K questions on SO with active close votes. I'm finding it very time-consuming to do a good job reviewing these, because simply opening the queue presents me with one question after another that I don't necessarily have the background expertise in. I end up spending lots of time fully evaluating the issue before voting, and that's a deterrent.

I know I can just keep clicking "skip", but that's only slightly better when searching for a needle in a haystack. (One tag I follow has just over 3000 questions, so the chances of stumbling across one of those in the close-vote queue is slim.)

What I want is to be able to find questions in the tags I know best, that need close-vote review. Is there already some clever way to do that? If not - consider this a feature request!

**Corollary:** In the tags I'm most active in, I've been confused by questions that were closed, usually as "not a real question", when anyone with a background in the topic would recognize them as valid and complete. When I've bothered checking on the profiles of the voters, I've noticed that few, if any, had any activity on that tag. The implication being that we, as a community, could do a better job if we were able to focus our close-vote review activities.

Comment: If you were searching for ["close vote tags"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close+vote+tags), say, that dup isn't anywhere near the top of the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the filter to do so. It is next to "Close votes":

> [image]

I would draw a beautiful red circle around "filter" but I do not have any tool here. I hope it is clear enough :)

---

Update: thanks [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard) & [Lucifer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/173001/lucifer) for providing these beautiful circles to make my answer more clear :)

> [image]

Comment: +1 , I was just about to post this answer with Image but you got it first :)

Comment: @Lucifer like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oT2Px.png)? Or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YNsHx.png)? ;) Hate to waste free hand circles, so now they exist forever!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That was just a little too obvious... time for coffee!

Comment: @fedorqui feel free to adapt my screenshot, see previous comment.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, second one is better, but red lines are very thin :P

Comment: @Lucifer only 2 pixels! :D

Comment: Thanks, @ShaWizDowArd!! Just updated my answer with your pictures. Hope there is no copyright hehe

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd how about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WzoDq.png)

Comment: @Lucifer two in one, cool!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are done, @Mogsdad!

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui - I tried to accept immediately, but there's that 10-minute rule. I saw something shiny, and wandered off...

Comment: Haha no problem @Mogsdad It happens to the best of us :)